# Batch file not working?

Tags: batch-file

It is supposed to split the thing you type in then set each character to a different variable. What it does now is make a ton of blank lines after you type the first thing in. Here it is:

```
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:home
set ran=%random%
if exist "%temp%\%ran%temp.txt" goto home
set /p o=""
rem putting %o% in temp file
echo.%o%>>"%temp%\%ran%temp.txt"
rem determaning num of bytes in txt file
for %%a in (%temp%\%ran%temp.txt) do set /a ol=%%~za
rem subtracting 2 from num of bytes
set /a ol -=2
rem Deleting temp file
del "%temp%\%ran%temp.txt"
goto pla
:pla
set v=0
set a=-1
set b=0
:pl
set /a v+=1
set /a a+=1
set /a b+=1
set var%v%=!o:~%a%,%b%!
if %b% == %ol% goto show
goto pl
:show
set vv=0
:showw
set /a vv+=1
echo.!var%vv%!
if %vv% == %v% goto end
goto showw
:end
pause
goto home
```

I edited the code a bit and now I get:

H

el

llo

lo

o

If I type in Hello.

I expect Example: I type "Hello" it should say

H

e

l

l

o

Comment: Wow, it's just like reading FORTRAN! Incidentally, how about showing the output you get and the output you expect?

Comment: @sarnold "What it does now is make a ton of blank lines after you type the first thing in." and read my new edit at the bottom.

Comment: If you know a code that will change the var to one character that would be really helpful!

Comment: Try `%a%,%a%` instead of `%a%,%b%`?

Comment: Hey i figured it out! I needed `set var%v%=!o:~%a%,1!` instead of `set var%v%=!o:~%a%,%b%!`

Comment: Would you look at that... My question got answered without anyone posting an answer......

Comment: Don't forget to post your solution as an answer once the system lets you.

Comment: If you change this statement: `echo.%o%>>"%temp%\%ran%temp.txt"` to this: `<nul >"%temp%\%ran%temp.txt" set /p o=%o%`, you will not need to subtract 2 after getting the size.

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me. Below is my own version of what *I think* you want to achieve. I apologize if you are not interested in my program (just ignore it, in this case)...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:home
set /p o=""
set v=0
:pl
   set /a v+=1
   set var%v%=%o:~0,1%
   set o=%o:~1%
if defined o goto pl
for /L %%v in (1,1,%v%) do echo.!var%%v!
pause
goto home
```